# a problem this my maven project "An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project". "

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I can clean install and clean package, as well as run the project but for some reason this error is displayed with my maven spring-boot project, can anyone help?
it makes coding so much difficult as it doesn't auto complete and give fake errors

[image]

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
'org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.ProjectConfigurationRequest.getMavenProject()'
```

Comment: Sounds like something is thoroughly broken. Try reinstalling the Maven plugin, or even Eclipse itself. Or better yet, upgrade to IntelliJ.

Comment: thanks for your advice, it turns out eclipse was the problem, I don't know why but when I used intelliJ it worked fine.

Comment: Delete all project from the eclipse workspace an reimport the whole project....

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed everything the problem was still there, however changing the IDE to intelliJ solved it.

Thanks to Jorn for the idea.